# Remove second browser scroll bar hover mega menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

We have a website that uses a mega menu. We want to remove the second scroll bar that appears on the left side of the mega menu web on mouse hover. URL : https://hikvision.zone/

[attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPulH.png)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp

Comment: Please check [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a scrollable div

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h1 {
                   color: green;
            }
            div.scroll {
                margin:4px, 4px;
                padding:4px;
                background-color: black;
                width: 500px;
                height: 110px;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: auto;
                text-align:justify;
                                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <h1>Scrolling</h1>
        <div class="scroll">It is a good platform to learn programming.
        It is an educational website. Prepare for the Recruitment drive
        of product based companies like Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc with
        a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses
        on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the
        interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and
        successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing
        articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few
        steps that are Articles that need little modification/improvement
        from reviewers are published first. To quickly get your articles
        reviewed, please refer existing articles, their formatting style,
        coding style, and try to make you are close to them. In case you
        are a beginner, you may refer Guidelines to write an Article
        </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of removing the scroll bars

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h1 {
            color:Green;
            }
            div.scroll {
                margin:4px, 4px;
                padding:4px;
                background-color: black;
                width: 500px;
                height: 110px;
                overflow: hidden;
                text-align:justify;
                             color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <h1>Scrolling</h1>
        <div class="scroll">It is a good platform to learn programming.
        It is an educational website. Prepare for the Recruitment drive
        of product based companies like Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc with
        a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses
        on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the
        interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and
        successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing
        articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few
        steps that are Articles that need little modification/improvement
        from reviewers are published first. To quickly get your articles
        reviewed, please refer existing articles, their formatting style,
        coding style, and try to make you are close to them. In case you
        are a beginner, you may refer Guidelines to write an Article
        </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the scrollable div in our css we added:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

for it to be scrollable

In our none scrollable div we added:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

To hide our scroll bars

here is a link to the website https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/making-a-div-vertically-scrollable-using-css/ to which I got my scrollable code

Comment: hi. overflow hidden not hiding the second scroll bar

Comment: Hi, would it be possible for us to have you navbar code so we can try and fix on our computer

Comment: It might probably have something to do with padding or margin with your navbar or dropdown menu